# Virtual memory in OS

Tags: virtual-memory

I have been trying to understand the virtual address space concept used by the running programs. Let me work with an example of 32-bit application running on 32-bit Windows OS .

As far as I have understood each process considers(or "thinks") itself as the only application running on the system (is this correct?) and it has access to 4GB addresses out of which, in standard configuration, 2 GB is allocated to kernel and 2 to the user process. I have the following questions on this:

1. Why does a user process need to have kernel code loaded in its address space? Why can't the kernel have its own full 4 GB address space so that each process can enjoy 4GB space?
2. In 2GB+2GB configuration, is 2GB sufficient for Kernel to load all its code? Surely all the application code making up the kernel is(or can be) more than 2GB? Similarly, a user process which is allocated the 2GB address space surely needs more than 2 GB when you consider its own code as well as the other dependencies such as dlls?
3. Another question I have on this topic is about the various locations where a running process is present on the computer system -Say for example I have a program C:\Program Files\MyApp\app.exe. When I launch it, it's loaded into the process using virtual address space and uses paging (pagefile.sys) to use the limited RAM. My question is, once app.exe is launched, does it load into RAM+Pagefile in its entirety or it only loads a portion of the program from C:\Program Files\MyApp\myapp.exe and hence it keeps on referring to the exe location for more as and when needed?
4. Last question - On a 32-bit OS if i had more than 4 GB RAM, can the memory management use the RAM space in excess of 4 GB or it goes waste?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

> Why does a user process need to have kernel code loaded in its address
>   space? Why can't the kernel have its own full 4 GB address space so
>   that each process can enjoy 4GB space?

A process can have (a tiny little bit less than) 4 GiB. The problem is that converting virtual addresses into physical addresses is expensive, so the CPU uses a "translation look-aside buffer" (TLB) to speed it up; and (at least on older CPUs) changing the virtual address space (e.g. because the kernel is in its own virtual address space) causes TLB entries to be discarded, which causes (virtual) memory accesses to become slow (because of "TLB misses"). Mapping the kernel into all virtual address spaces avoids/avoided this performance problem.

*Note: For modern CPUs with the "PCID" feature the performance problem can be avoided by giving each virtual address space an ID; but most operating systems were designed before this feature existed, so (even with meltdown patches) they still use virtual address spaces in the same way.*

> In 2GB+2GB configuration, is 2GB sufficient for Kernel to load all its
>   code? Surely all the application code making up the kernel is more
>   than 2GB? Similarly, a user process which is allocated the 2GB address
>   space surely needs more than 2 GB when you consider its own code as
>   well as the other dependencies such as dlls?

Code is never the problem - its data. In general, most software either doesn't need 2 GiB of space or needs more than 4 GiB of space; and there's very little that needs 2 GiB but doesn't need more than 4 GiB. For things that need more than 4 GiB of space, everything shifted to 64 bit (typically with 131072 GiB or more of "user space") about 10 years ago, so...

> My question is, once app.exe is launched, does it load into RAM+Pagefile in its entirety or it only loads a portion of the program from C:\Program Files\MyApp\myapp.exe and hence it keeps on referring to the exe location for more as and when needed?

Most modern operating systems use "memory mapped files". The idea is that the executable file isn't initially loaded into RAM at all, but if/when something within a page is actually accessed the first time it causes a "page fault" and the page fault handler fetches the page from disk. This tends to reduce RAM consumption (stuff that isn't accessed is never loaded from disk) and improve process start up times.

> On a 32-bit OS if i had more than 4 GB RAM, can the memory management use the RAM space in excess of 4 GB or it goes waste?

There are multiple virtual address spaces where virtual addresses might be 32 bits wide, and a single physical address space where (depending on extensions that the CPU supports) physical addresses might be 36 bits wide (or even wider). This means that you could have a 32-bit OS running on a "32-bit only" CPU that can effectively use up to (e.g.) 64 GiB of RAM (if you can find a motherboard that actually supports it). In this case the CPU still converts virtual addresses into physical addresses, and processes needn't be aware of the physical address size; but a single process won't be able to use all of the RAM by itself (you'd need many processes to use all the RAM).

Answer (score 1):

> Why does a user process need to have kernel code loaded in its address space? Why can't the kernel have its own full 4 GB address space so that each process can enjoy 4GB space?

There normally are no kernel processes (except for the NULL process). Most CPU's process exceptions and interrupts in the the context of the currently running process. To support that, the kernel needs to be in the same location and have the same layout in all processes. Otherwise, an interrupt occurring during one process would be handled differently than one occurring while another process is running.

> In 2GB+2GB configuration, is 2GB sufficient for Kernel to load all its code? Surely all the application code making up the kernel is(or can be) more than 2GB? Similarly, a user process which is allocated the 2GB address space surely needs more than 2 GB when you consider its own code as well as the other dependencies such as dlls?

You have misconception here. The there is no application code in the kernel space. The kernel space code only executes in response to an interrupt or exception.

2GB is more than sufficient for any kernel I have seen. In fact, some 32-bit systems (where the hardware permits it) make the kernel space less than 2GB and increase the size of the user space accordingly.

> Another question I have on this topic is about the various locations where a running process is present on the computer system -Say for example I have a program C:\Program Files\MyApp\app.exe. When I launch it, it's loaded into the process using virtual address space and uses paging (pagefile.sys) to use the limited RAM. My question is, once app.exe is launched, does it load into RAM+Pagefile in its entirety or it only loads a portion of the program from C:\Program Files\MyApp\myapp.exe and hence it keeps on referring to the exe location for more as and when needed?

That depends upon the system. On any rationally designed system, secondary storage will be allocated to back every valid page in the process user address space. The "where" depends upon the system. For example, some systems use the executable as the page file for the code and static data. Only the writeable data will go to the page file. However, some primitive operating systems do not support paging directly to a file in that manner.

> Last question - On a 32-bit OS if i had more than 4 GB RAM, can the memory management use the RAM space in excess of 4 GB or it goes waste?

That depends upon the system. It is possible for a 32-bit OS to use more than 4GB of RAM. Each process is limited go 4GB but the various process can use more than 4GB of physical memory.

Let's say that you have 4K pages. That 12-bits. In theory a 32-bit processor could have 64 bit page table entries. In that case the processor could easily access more than 4GB of physical memory.

The more common case is that a 32-bit processor has 32-bit page table entries. In theory a 32-bit page table with 4K pages could access 2 ^ (32 + 12) bytes of memory. In practice some of the 32 bits in the page table entry have to be used for system purposes. If there are fewer than 12 control bits, the processor can use more than 4GB of physical memory.

Comment: Thank you. You have cleared many of my doubts. What you are saying is that kernel should never be seen as another "process" instead it's a set of privileged instructions which are mapped/present in every process virtual address space(higher end) and can be executed as a result of an exception to run in privileged mode. Thanks again.